# Editing Terminal promt with dynamic text derived from pwd

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, command-prompt

## Short version

Use this prompt to get this green color:

[image: prompt with green]

With this line:

```sh
export PS1="\w: \[$(tput setaf 2)\][GREEN]\[$(tput sgr 0)\] \$ "
```

But to work inside a function so

```sh
my_function(){
  echo -e "\[$(tput setaf 2)\][GREEN]\[$(tput sgr 0)\]"
  # echo "\[$(tput setaf 2)\][GREEN]\[$(tput sgr 0)\]"
}
export PS1="\w: \$(my_function) \$ "
```

Unfortunately I get this prompt : `~/Work/temp/prompt_test: \[\][GREEN]\[\] $`

[image]

*You mustn't use `$(my_function)` instead of `\$(my_function)` - why? elaborate explanation below.

## Elaborate explanation

I'm trying to satisfy 2 conditions:

### Condition 1

I can add color to prompt with this code:

```sh
export PS1="\w: $(tput setaf 2)GREEN$(tput sgr 0) \$ "
```

[image: prompt with green]

But then If I enter a long command, then click `home` + `end`- something become messed up - to replicate behavior:

1. `export PS1="\w: $(tput setaf 2)GREEN$(tput sgr 0) \$ "`
2. type a long command (no enter): `longg command with many charterssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss`
3. click `home`
4. click `end`
5. Try deleteing all chars using `backspace`

[image]

I can fix that adding `\[` and `\]` before and after `color commands`:

```sh
export PS1="\w: \[$(tput setaf 2)\]GREEN\[$(tput sgr 0)\] \$ "
```

That solves the problem.
Lets call "preventing that problem" **Condition 1**

### Condition 2

To have the PS1 line evaluate **dynamically** with every directory change.
so given the following structure (basically making two folders: `mkdir blue red`)
two folders:
  +-- red
  +-- blue

Then a simple bash function to check whether `pwd` contain `blue` or `red` then add color to prompt so whenever I change to folder with `blue` path I get `blue`, same with `red`

```sh
change_color2(){
  local my_pwd=$(pwd)
  if [[ $my_pwd == *"blue"* ]]; then # path containing 'blue'
    echo "$(tput setaf 4)<BLUE>$(tput sgr 0)"
  elif [[ $my_pwd == *"red"* ]]; then # path containing 'red'
    echo "$(tput setaf 1)<RED>$(tput sgr 0)"
  fi
}
export PS1="\w: \$(change_color2) \$ "
cd red
cd blue
```

[image]

Notice this doesn't work if I use `$(change_color2)` instead of `\$(change_color2)`

I'm trying to satisfy both conditions at once but I'm unable to- can you please help?
Thank you.

`Ubuntu 20.04`
`/bin/bash`

Comment: Your question is only quasi-programming related, it's more "How to use `tput`?" and "How to modify the Linux prompt?" That said, when you include control characters within the prompt, the escaped characters cannot be counted accurately  This results in an incorrect internal prompt-length which explains why your **[Home]** and **[End]** and then **[Backspace]** fails to properly clear the command. You will likely get more of a response on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin A valid point- I will try there thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pynexj mentioned in his answer and with [This Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1565923/924880) the solution is to use `PROMPT_COMMAND` which is a function being evaluated before the PS1.

So I can do

```sh
my_function(){
  echo -e "\[$(tput setaf 2)\][GREEN]\[$(tput sgr 0)\]"
  # echo "\[$(tput setaf 2)\][GREEN]\[$(tput sgr 0)\]"
}
update_PS1 () {
  PS1="\w: $(my_function) \$ "
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=update_PS1
# export PS1="\w: \$(my_function) \$ "
```

And this time inside `update_PS1` I'm using `$(my_function)`, not `\$(my_function)` but that's OK- it still apply to condition 2 due to using `PROMPT_COMMAND` the `PS` variable is being evaluated every time I change new folder.

Comment: This is also a good example why if you use `printf` for output, you don't have to worry about options to process control codes `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't understand- How would one use `printf` in the example given?

Comment: With `echo` you must tell it to process escapes with `echo -e`, `printf` processes escapes in its format string by default.